# Best Drupal theme for dashboard site?

Tags: drupal

I'm new to Drupal. It looks like there are thousands of themes. For efficiency's sake, I've come here to ask if anyone can help point me in a better direction: I'm looking for a Drupal theme that'll be most friendly out of the box to a dashboard system (similar to [this](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview)). Any thoughts/advice?

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to AdminLTE theme which is available for Drupal: [Drupal 8](https://github.com/marcinmaruszewski/gabinet-lte) and [Drupal 7](https://github.com/umandalroald/adminlte).

Also take a look at the [Adminimal](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) theme.